# Initialising 'CGVector' aka ('struct CGVector') with an expression of incompatible type int

Tags: ios, objective-c

The last three lines of the code below generate the warning

> Initialising 'CGVector' aka ('struct CGVector') with an expression of
>   incompatible type int

What does that warning mean, and what should I do to fix it?

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{

    CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;

    for(SKNode *enemyNode in _enemies) {
        CGPoint enemyPos = enemyNode.position;

        /* Uniform speed: */
        CGVector diff = TCVectorMinus(playerPos, enemyPos);
        CGVector normalized = TCVectorUnit(diff);
        CGVector force = TCVectorMultiply(normalized, 4);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you also happen to have any earlier warnings about implicit declarations of any functions?

Comment: I assume that there's a header file that you need to `#import` to declare those functions.

Comment: "incompatible type __int__" learn how to read error message.

Comment: Missing #import was the problem! Thanks for the response, I'd totally missed that it was missing!